# How to get text inside javascript tag using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

example :

```
<script>
var TEST = { "contextData" :
{id:01,title:one},{id:02,title:two},{id:03,title:three}}
</script>
```

how to get all title ? using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, I just have no idea to do this.

Comment: Have you tried json_decode?

Comment: That's not really json. It's not html either, which means... use regex.

Comment: Would you give an example of its ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is not tested but should work:

- Get the script using `$script = $html->find('script', 0);`
- Use the following pattern, with [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) as suggested by @pguardiario, to get the titles value: `/title\s*:\s*([^}]+)/`

<kbd>[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pV9zV9)</kbd>

**EDIT:**

And to get all titles and desc (different of qwerty) modify the pattern to: `/(title|desc)\s*:\s*(?!qwerty)([^},]+)/`

<kbd>[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cP5fT9)</kbd>

Comment: @Enisay: thanks it's work. how if this example
`{id:01,title:one,desc:abc},{id:02,title:two,desc:cde},{id:03,title:three,desc:efg}}`


i want result all title and desc ?

Comment: wow thanks :) one example again, hehe
`{id:01,title:one,desc:qwerty},{id:02,title:two,desc:cde},{id:03,title:three,desc:efg}}`
i want result all title and desc , but not desc "qwerty" ?